# Export module js not working (npm i BigInt )

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

i m working with a module named BigInt.js with angular 4 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/BigInt ) and when i run my projet (ng serve) these warnings occurs 
[image: warnings]

and then when trying to use this module it becomes an error like so

[image: error]

i realize that the problem is with the exportation of the module but i didn't know how to fix that ! 
this is the BigInt.js code! 
the error is exactly is this  line  `factory(require, exports, module);`

```js
    (function(factory) {
    if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // CommonJS
        factory(require, exports, module);
    } else if (typeof define === 'function') {
        // AMD requirejs
        define(factory);
    } else {
        // Plain script tag
        var _module = {};
        _module.exports = {};
        var _require = function(name) { throw new Error("can't require"); }
        factory(_require, _module.exports, _module);
        window.BigInt = _module.exports;
    }
})(function (require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    //all the bigint functions 

 module.exports = {
      //Export all functions
    };

});
```

Any help ?

Comment: This actually works fine directly form the browser, it turns out your problem has to do something with webpack.

Comment: yeah ! i actually tried to install the module and use it without webpack and it works fine !

Comment: It seems a bad path, webpack is unable to find your module, review the webpack configuration and make sure you're giving the correct paths to find your module.